# '>' is not recognising as a command line Argument ? How to Pass this as a command Line Argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, command-line-arguments

Python Program:

```
import sys

print(len(sys.argv))
```

Command Line:

Without '>' Operator

```
>>> python sample.py 1 2 3
```

Output:

```
4
```

With '>' Operator

```
>>> python sample.py > 1 2
```

Output:

Not Showing Anything

How to make it as a Command Line Argument, Without Using Any Quotes.
I need it because I am implementing Cat command with python.

Comment: You can't, and why would you want to?

Comment: When you use `>` (and `<`) it is a *redirection* to (or from) a file. After the second command, you should have a file named `1` which contains the output. This redirection is handled by the shell, not by Python or your program.

Comment: `>`, `<`, `&` have [special meaning](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) when it comes to the command line, you need to quote it or escape it for the shell to pass in the character literally to your program.

Comment: ...depending on the shell there are about a dozen other characters that have special meanings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since by using `>`, you can print your Terminal or CMD output to a file, u need to use it with double quotations around
You need to use it like: `python sample.py ">" 1 2`